# Notifications bar lags when onGoing notification is on

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-preferences, android-notifications, batterylevel

My application has a notification in the notifications bar that shows the battery level. The notification works but when the checkbox in the preferences is clicked and the notification appears, i try to pull down the notifications bar and it lags. I don't know way but i think that it's because the notification check every second the battery level but i'm not sure.. I post the code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void checkPref(Intent intent){ 
            this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            SharedPreferences myPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this); 
            boolean pref_opt1 = myPref.getBoolean("firstDependent", false); 
            int level= intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
            if (pref_opt1){
                NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                 .setContentTitle("Battery Informations")
                 .setContentText("Battery level"+" "+level+"%")
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_not)
                 //.setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
                 .setTicker(level+"%")
                 .build();

                 notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
                 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class); 
                 PendingIntent penInt = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 , i , 0);
                 notifi.notify(215,notification);
                } else {
                NotificationManager notifi = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notifi.cancel(215);
                }
        }
```

Maybe the problem is this one `this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));`. But i know only this way to update the notification when the battery level changes.. Some helps please?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether 'if-case' code to show notification is getting executed repeatedly. If so try **limiting show notification to once via a flag** value and reset the flag during notifi.cancel().